# meaning of "Figures" in this context

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

> "Ach," laughs the baker's wife, "such a funny man, the Count."
>
> "I knew you'd like that," Dracula says, forcing a chuckle, "now get out of my way." At last he opens the front door but time has run out on him.
>
> "Oh, look, mama," says the baker, "the eclipse must be over. The sun is coming out again."
>
> "Right," says Dracula, slamming the front door. "I've decided to stay. Pull down the window shades quickly— quickly! Let's move it!"
>
> "What window shades?" asks the baker.
>
> "There are none, right? **Figures**. You got a basement in this joint?"

Dose it refer to baker and his wife and is the polite way to call someone?

This passage is from a story named: Count Dracula by Woody Allen.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, "Figures!" is an informal way to say "Obviously". It is a shortened form of [**"I should have figured it out myself!"**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/it-figures)

Comment: ... or sometimes "That figures" = "That makes sense", not necessarily obviously, and sometimes with the sense "I should have expected that, given my bad luck."

Comment: @jonathanjo: Yes, you are correct.